# How to check if NodeList contains any children?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, nodelist

Is there an easy and simple way to check if a NodeList that I evaluate from an xpath actually contains any child nodes, or if it's just empty tags?
Take this simple xml as an example:

```
<shop>
  <shoes>brand1</shoes>
  <tshirt>brand2</tshirt>
  <socks>brand3</socks>
</shop>
```

If I run

```
 NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) path.evaluate("/shop", myDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

I'll get a nice NodeList that I can extract the various shoes, tshirt and socks values from. That's fine. But what if I have an xml that looks like this:

```
<shop>
</shop>
```

Running the same command will give me a NodeList of length 1, and I'd rather not continue with the extraction process if I already know it contains nothing.

Other than checking if `nodeList.item(0).getChildNodes().getLength() == 1`, is there another way to check for empty childNodes?

Comment: Looking at the documentation for [Node](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) you could do `nodelist.item(0).hasChildNodes()`

Comment: `nodeList.getLength();`? What implementation of the NodeList you use? Probably you can share more code to make your question clearer.

Comment: nodeList.getLength() will return 1 for both cases, and nodeList.item(0).hasChildNodes() will return true for both cases

Comment: Try `/shop[child::*]` (or simple `//shop[*]`) to get only non-empty `shop`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check it using `"/shop/*"` xpath and `getLength()` method. Like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws XPathExpressionException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {

        String myDocumentStr = "<shop><shoes>brand1</shoes><tshirt>brand2</tshirt><socks>brand3</socks></shop>";
        Node myDocument = getNode(myDocumentStr);

        XPathExpression path = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().compile("/shop/*");

        NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) path.evaluate(myDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);

        System.out.println(nodeList.getLength());

        myDocumentStr = "<shop></shop>";
        myDocument = getNode(myDocumentStr);
        nodeList = (NodeList) path.evaluate(myDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);

        System.out.println(nodeList.getLength());
    }

    private static Node getNode(String myDocumentStr) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Node myDocument = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(myDocumentStr.getBytes()));
        return myDocument;
    }
```

Output:

```
3
0
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That's what I wanted